# AngularJS - remove bindings to avoid memory leaks

Tags: javascript, data-binding, memory-leaks, angularjs

What is the proper way in AngularJS to disconnect bindings?

I have a none-angular application which is loading a component that uses angularjs to do data-binding. At some point I want to destroy the component and want to be sure that there are no memory leaks.  How do I tell angular to remove all event listeners from that part of the DOM?

Would `$(node).remove()` do the trick, or does angular do other things in memory that need to be cleaned up...?  Any other tips on avoiding mem-leaks in angular would be appreciated.

Answer (score 10):

Just removing a DOM element that has a Scope with something like `remove()` will not get rid of the Scope in memory. You can confirm this by removing an element and looking in [Batarang](https://github.com/angular/angularjs-batarang), or by getting the parent scope and examining it's children. You'll see the scope is still there.... So you'll also want to call `$destroy()` on the Scope itself.

[More information about $destroy() can be found here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope).

EDIT: One thing I'm not sure of, is if it deletes the scope entirely, or just disconnects it and lets JavaScript GC take care of the rest.

Comment: the docs say there is also a jQuery event to unbind the scope and DOM element but does not give an example use case. Is it just a case of finding the elements scope, invoking the destroy method and then using jquery remove()? It seems strange this functionality does not exist as a complete function inside angular!

Comment: if you assign a scope to window.leak and then set a console log on scope.$on('destroy',...) you will see destroy is called but you can still access the scope from the leak.

Comment: @Chris Stephens If you add it to `windom.leak`, wouldn't this prevent the garbage collector from being able to dispose of it?

Comment: @thetallweeks I don't quite remember what I replying too however I believe it was about the EDIT in the answer, if angular physically deletes the scope or if it just disconnects it for GC. If you attach it to window it will create a leak so that shows that it does not physically delete it.